# ssh2 module with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, browserify

I'm using [this code here](http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/how-to-upload-a-file-over-ssh-using-node-js/) to transfer a file from my computer to a remote server, using the ssh2 module in node. It works perfectly when I use node directly for the job but I want to transfer the file from my browser using SSH.

I was thinking I could use browserify for the job. My idea was that a user presses a button in the browser and the bundle.js script tag activates the above linked module, allowing the user selected file to be transferred to the server.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem as far as I know with trying to use something like ssh2 with browserify is that the crypto in browserify is lacking still. Also the other big problem is that there is no shim/polyfill for plain TCP sockets in the browser (for now). I did see a project where someone had a client/server thing for browserify to emulate TCP sockets, but it doesn't look like it's maintained anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have any alternative suggestions for doing an SSH file transfer from the browser to a remote server?

Comment: You could always stream a file upload directly from the browser to the server which handles the ssh/sftp connection (or save the file upload to disk first and then transfer it via ssh/sftp).

Comment: OK, so I could create a webserver using node, have the browser send the user selected file to it and get the webserver to do the ssh/sftp file transfer to the remote server?

Comment: Correct, that's probably the best way to do it for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate! If I get a decent solution out, I'll post it here so others can benefit.