# Fail to bundle node ssh2 with webpack/browserify

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, ssh, google-chrome-extension, browserify

I am currently trying to build a Chrome extension that uses ssh to connect to a server. I am currently using the [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) node module, but when I fail to bundle it using browserify.

I found this thread from 2014: [ssh2 module with browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377087/ssh2-module-with-browserify)

Is there a workaround at this point? Or has anyone another idea how I might access ssh inside the extension?

How come there is a [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) that can provide an ssh-Terminal?

Comment: Create a native application that accesses ssh. Extensions communicate with it via native messaging.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate, or provide any resources on that?

Comment: So is the Native Messaging API just able to communicate with the current web page? I am trying to connect to a separate Apache server

Comment: Please see this. [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging)

Comment: So should I use native messaging to open a terminal/cmd window? Or how should I use it to connect to the server using a native app already installed on the computer?